# How to convert DatePicker Value to String?

Tags: java, string, date, datepicker

I'm trying to convert the

`datepicker.getvalue();`

**into a String**(or into something else, which I can then use to insert into my mysql database), but I've been having troubles finding information about that!

**Have you got any suggestions?**
Thanks! :)

**EDIT:** This solves the problem

```
String date = datepicker.getValue().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Comment: `datepicker.getvalue().toString()`. `datepicker.getvalue().format(...)`

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on that? I did try the first example before posting this question, but it didn't solve my problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the string value of selected date with desire format like below :

```
String date = datepicker.getValue().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

**or**
you can get java.sql.Date straight away to your database table :

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate =java.sql.Date.valueOf(datepicker.getValue());
```

Comment: Your second line maybe will invokes an exception when the value is null.